# AVMulticam Like Dualgram

Tags: swift, avcapturesession

I'm making application like dual gram (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/dualgram/id1474345188), but I'm facing issue to record the videos with different layouts, like this application, anyone can help me in this.
Thanks

Comment: Try to be more specific, tell us the things have you tried and what specifically did not work, share some of your code and tell us what did you expect and what is actually happening

Comment: I used this sample code(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/capture_setup/avmulticampip_capturing_from_multiple_cameras), and I want to move the corner view(Different layout for e.g grid view), but I didn't get that output, it's always the same output one layer is in full screen and other is in top right corner.